# Goodness of fit for in-sample predictions

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

This is probably a stupid question that I'm overthinking, and apologies if it's super obvious, but -

Say you have some regression model `y ~ f(x1, x2...)` that you fit to data. Call this the 'main model' for now.

You get your regression from the main model, and you use a `predict` type function to yield in-sample predicted `y` values (let's say `y*`) for all the observed `x1, x2...` in your data. Now, `y*` are predicted values for `y`, so let's say we now run a simple linear regression with the model `y ~ y*` - call this the 'simple model'.

My question is, should various goodness-of-fit statistics (e.g. RMSE, R^2) for the main model and the simple model be identical? Why or why not?
(Unless 'why' is "because they're literally the same thing", in which case feel free to just say that!)

Edit: tested with following code:

```
> test_data
# A tibble: 20 × 3
          y    x1     x2
      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -0.0149   21.8  0.487
 2 -0.0170   23.8  0.131
 3  0.0128   20.8  0.733
 4 -0.0204   24.3  0.327
 5 -0.0401   23.1  0.404
 6  0.0930   21.2  0.926
 7 -0.0513   22.0  0.529
 8 -0.129    30.3 -0.715
 9 -0.0170   23.8  0.131
10 -0.0409   22.3  0.442
11 -0.137    21.3  0.446
12 -0.0338   25.9  0.316
13 -0.00822  22.3  0.648
14  0.0345   20.8  0.643
15  0.0471   24.3  0.200
16 -0.00650  21.5  0.547
17 -0.0486   22.1  0.901
18 -0.0737   28.5 -0.297
19  0.0234   26.8  0.118
20 -0.00890  24.0  0.546

main <- lm("y ~ x1 + x2", test_data)
test_data$y_pred <- predict(main) # Add predictions from main model
simple <- lm("y ~ y_pred", test_data) # Regress observed against predicted
```

Here are the `summary` results for the main and simple models:

```
> summary(main)

Call:
lm(formula = "y ~ x1 + x2", data = test_data)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.106462 -0.019905 -0.003817  0.030844  0.083208 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.240293   0.245335  -0.979   0.3411  
x1           0.007453   0.009491   0.785   0.4431  
x2           0.115037   0.064026   1.797   0.0902 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04826 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2788,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1939 
F-statistic: 3.286 on 2 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.06216

> summary(simple)

Call:
lm(formula = "y ~ y_pred", data = test_data)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.106462 -0.019905 -0.003817  0.030844  0.083208 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -6.517e-17  1.336e-02   0.000   1.0000  
y_pred       1.000e+00  3.791e-01   2.638   0.0167 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0469 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2788,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2387 
F-statistic: 6.958 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.01671
```

So it looks like the multiple R-squared is the same, but the adjusted R-squared, F, and p-value are different, which I assume is because the degrees of freedom are slightly different for each model?

The RMSE looks like it's the same though:

```
> sqrt(mean(simple$residuals ^2))
[1] 0.04449425
> sqrt(mean(main$residuals ^2))
[1] 0.04449425
```

---

Test data here:

```
structure(list(y = c(-0.0149054927871505, -0.0170137466591455, 
0.0128318420089774, -0.0204478017687445, -0.0401227514812484, 
0.0929525887669447, -0.0513457972324178, -0.129018618587365, 
-0.0170137466591455, -0.040857954317206, -0.136977183779344, 
-0.0337755478138668, -0.0082243454229032, 0.0344788355710609, 
0.0471334903603776, -0.00649550644694302, -0.0485828575527817, 
-0.0737301275807424, 0.0233928795747054, -0.00889576418458499
), x1 = c(21.7906349206349, 23.79425, 20.8316981132075, 24.3160526315789, 
23.1439393939394, 21.1842857142857, 21.995956284153, 30.2811392405063, 
23.79425, 22.2793373493976, 21.2571212121212, 25.9298611111111, 
22.3015584415584, 20.8416, 24.3116129032258, 21.505, 22.1379824561403, 
28.5379207920792, 26.7947887323944, 23.9788148148148), x2 = c(0.487459583729331, 
0.131205294570451, 0.733106660831697, 0.326525914159468, 0.404294159066793, 
0.92635727520522, 0.529406871129557, -0.715495784602749, 0.131205294570451, 
0.442094223229665, 0.446343589682511, 0.316249126379862, 0.647954821964668, 
0.64301642106813, 0.200120016662466, 0.546638394449764, 0.900781869154798, 
-0.296739694460581, 0.118212601580376, 0.546327126903104), y_pred = c(`1` = -0.021808691493989, 
`2` = -0.0478577256820188, `3` = -0.000697387783133552, `4` = -0.0214996272484705, 
`5` = -0.0212893728657664, `6` = 0.0241613984725961, `7` = -0.0154529257119745, 
`8` = -0.0969115624454971, `9` = -0.0478577256820188, `10` = -0.0233849941968201, 
`11` = -0.0305148963963352, `12` = -0.0106538699900019, `13` = 0.000462129290600535, 
`14` = -0.0109872636341906, `15` = -0.0360740236786066, `16` = -0.0171298427121645, 
`17` = 0.0283273396363096, `18` = -0.0617317563447944, `19` = -0.0269888819695119, 
`20` = 0.0012720744442658)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You could make a great deal of progress yourself, and helpfully focus this question, by actually trying what you propose.  Inspect the outputs of the original and new regression: how do they differ?

Comment: @whuber tried it out, shared example above. I can see some things are the same and others different, is there a more general explanation for what should or shouldn't be the same?

Comment: Because the RMSE is the same, the *only* source of differences is that you have fooled the software into believing you have only one explanatory variable, $y^*,$ instead of more than one.  BTW, I'm sure you could come up with a *much* simpler test dataset.  Try three datapoints and one explanatory variable (but don't include an intercept in the second fit).  `y <- c(1,0,2);
summary(fit.0 <- lm(y ~ predict(fit <- lm(y ~ I(0:2))) + 0));
summary(fit)`